# How to get JSON object values filtered by a string?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a simple JSON array that contains roles and its permissions:

```js
var permission_list = {
  "admin": [
    "grant-all-access"
  ],
  "operation": [
    "wms-operation-read",
    "wms-operation-write"
  ],
  "logistics": [
    "wms-storage-read",
    "wms-storage-write"
  ],
  "cx": [a "wms-storage-read",
    "wms-storage-write"
  ],
  "normal_user": [
    "page-read",
    "page-write"
  ]
};
```

And I need to dynamically get each permission per role. Roles are being thrown from the backend but it is in string and I need to loop through the permission list by role.

Let's say I need to get only the "operation" permissions to add to a div element.

- wms-operation-read
- wms-operation-write

Here's what I tried:

```js
var role = "admin" // sample string thrown from ajax api from BE

$.each(permission_list, function(key, val) {
  console.log(key)
}); // returns the first level array
```

My idea was to loop through permission_list.role but don't know how to make it work.

I hope you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have access to `key` and `value` on each item in the `permission_list` object you can perform what ever you want within the callback which you pass as the second argument to `$.each` method like bellow

```js
var permission_list = {
    "admin": [
        "grant-all-access"
    ], 
    "operation": [
        "wms-operation-read",
        "wms-operation-write"
    ],
    "logistics": [
        "wms-storage-read",
        "wms-storage-write"
    ],
    "cx": [
        "wms-storage-read",
        "wms-storage-write"
    ],
    "normal_user": [
        "page-read",
        "page-write"
    ]
};

let container = document.querySelector("#root");

$.each(permission_list, function(key, value) {
    // key contains the object key
    // value contains the value at the given key in the permission_list object
    let template = [];
    container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<h2>${key}</h2>`);
    value.forEach(item => {
        template.push(`<p>${item}</p>`);
    });
    container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template.join(''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Yves! The code you wrote works, but this seems to list down all roles and permissions and I need to filter the listing per role.

Comment: You can perform the check within the callback to only perform the code you want when certain condition are validated

Answer (score 1):

If you know at runtime exactly what property of the `permission_list` object you need to get the roles for, `operation` in the example in your question, then you can access it directly and use a loop to get the values, eg.

```js
var permission_list = {admin:["grant-all-access"],operation:["wms-operation-read","wms-operation-write"],logistics:["wms-storage-read","wms-storage-write"],cx:["wms-storage-read","wms-storage-write"],normal_user:["page-read","page-write"]};

permission_list.operation.forEach(role => {
  console.log(role);
});
```

Taking this a step further, to add those role names to a `div` in the UI you can use `map()` to create an array of HTML strings which you `append()` where necessary:

```js
var permission_list = {admin:["grant-all-access"],operation:["wms-operation-read","wms-operation-write"],logistics:["wms-storage-read","wms-storage-write"],cx:["wms-storage-read","wms-storage-write"],normal_user:["page-read","page-write"]};

let html = permission_list.operation.map(role => `<div class="role">${role}</div>`);
$('#roles').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Operation:</h4>
<div id="roles"></div>
```

**-- UPDATE --**

Given your description of the goal in the question you can read the `data-role` from the clicked button then use bracket notation to retrieve the property from the object using that variable, something like this:

```js
let permission_list = {admin:["grant-all-access"],operation:["wms-operation-read","wms-operation-write"],logistics:["wms-storage-read","wms-storage-write"],cx:["wms-storage-read","wms-storage-write"],normal_user:["page-read","page-write"]};

$('#edit-perms').on('click', e => {
  let $btn = $(e.target);
  let html = permission_list[$btn.data('role')].map(role => `<div class="role">${role}</div>`);
  $('#roles').append(html);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="primary" id="edit-perms" data-user="bern" data-role="admin">Edit Permission</button>
<div id="roles"></div>
```

You could even loop through the keys of the object creating a button for each, if necessary:

```js
let permission_list = {admin:["grant-all-access"],operation:["wms-operation-read","wms-operation-write"],logistics:["wms-storage-read","wms-storage-write"],cx:["wms-storage-read","wms-storage-write"],normal_user:["page-read","page-write"]};

$('#buttons').append(Object.keys(permission_list).map(role => `<button class="primary" id="edit-perms" data-user="bern" data-role="${role}">${role}</button>`));

$('#buttons').on('click', 'button', e => {
  let $btn = $(e.target);
  let html = permission_list[$btn.data('role')].map(role => `<div class="role">${role}</div>`);
  $('#roles').html(html);
})
```

```css
button {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons"></div>
<div id="roles"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rory for your reply. Sorry if my question seems to be a bit confusing. Ideally, roles need to be mapped dynamically. Let's say role is a data attribute in a button that's being filled from the backend.

`<button class="primary" data-user="bern" data-role="admin">Edit Permission</button>`

I need to use the `$(".primary").data("role");` to loop through permission_list.

My idea was to make the click event look like this:
`var role = $(".primary").data("role");
permission_list.role.forEach(role => {
  console.log(role);
});`

Comment: No problem, I updated the answer to show you how to do that